# creating new variable by squaring the difference of two columns in dataframe

Tags: r

i want to substract and square the difference of two columns in dataframe by creating a new variable.

> IMDB1
>       imdbVotes   imdbRating
>       45          2700
>       56          750
>       N/A         800
>       67          1400
>       N/A         850

when i use this code

```
sub=IMDB$IMDBvote-IMDB$IMDBrating
```

i get

> In Ops.factor(IMDB1$imdbRating, IMDB1$imdbVotes) :
>     ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

.then later i used

```
votes=as.numeric(IMDB1$imdbVotes)
rating=as.numeric(IMDB1$imdbRating)
```

and checked still im getting

> ‘-’ not meaningful for factors.

please help me to get the square of difference of `imdbrating` and `imdbvoting` by creating new varibale

Comment: You have to first convert the factors into character before converting into numeric

Comment: can you plz give the code how to convert into character and later into numeric

Comment: i converted it into character and later into numeric votes=as.character(IMDB1$imdbVotes)
rating=as.character(IMDB1$imdbRating)votes=as.numeric(IMDB1$imdbVotes)
rating=as.numeric(IMDB1$imdbRating) ,then i applied sq=IMDB1$imdbRating-IMDB1$imdbVotes, still im getting In Ops.factor(IMDB1$imdbRating, IMDB1$imdbVotes) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Errors are very clear. You cannot subtract factors

Comment: Please make your example reproducable! Read [mcve] ... then edit your question! http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42021453/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
IMDB$IMDBvote <- as.numeric(as.character(IMDB$IMDBvote))
IMDB$IMDBrating <- as.numeric(as.character(IMDB$IMDBrating))
```

Then

```
sub=IMDB$IMDBvote-IMDB$IMDBrating
```

Comment: i used above code im getting-     NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Probably your data has strings or characters in between. Its not clean enough. These are simple errors and I suggest you to learn basics of R first before diving into these kind of things.

Comment: ya some of my data is blank i.e N/A. how to perform code now on unavailable data i,e substracting